# Move files during a composer-installation into top-level directory

Tags: php, composer-php

I want do create a composer-package that moves part of it's content into the directory containing the main `composer.json`-file.

At first I though about a simple post-installation script that could be hooked into composers installation procedure via `"scripts" : { "post-package-install":"MyScript"}`. But these scripts are only called when they are defined in the main `composer.json`. And I don't have access to that.

So my next idea was to use a custom installer. It took me some time to get through the concept and I'm sure I am missing something fundamental. As the custom-Installer (**Installer**) is a requirement to my package that contains the files that shall be moved (**Package**) the Installer is installed and executed before the Package. Therefore I have no chance of moving the contents of the Package somewhere as the package is not yet available.

Is there a possibility to accomplish that somehow?

If you need code-examples drop me a line, but at the moment I'm more stuck at how to do it anyway.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't know whether I really get your requirement of moving a directory one level up. But if you need to install the package on a different location, it is possible with installers. In auraphp v1 we did that via https://github.com/auraphp/installer-system . The code is a few lines and I assume you can easily understand. If not ping, happy to help.